# EntityFramework Querying data while migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

Is there any way to query the data while code first migration? When the method Up is performing, I would like to create a context and to be able to perform CRUD operations using C#.

I would like to use C# instead of SQL stored procedures etc. But when I try to create a context, the migration throws an exception saying that the context has some changes.

Comment: Posting exception might help.

Comment: You can't create `context`, because you located inside migration, that not applied yet, so `EF` will suggest you to update database to last migration. You should perform your manipulations manually via T-SQL i.e. `Sql("your script")`

Comment: If your goal is to check for existing data and do either an insert or update, see [here](http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/take-care-with-ef-4-3-addorupdate-method/)